# API Breaks past 8-9 Devices?

Tags: nest-api

It would seem that streaming breaks when there is too many devices in the account.  After about 8 or 9 it just stops streaming data to me all together.

Comment: Can you please tell us what exactly breaks? By stop streaming does it mean the connection is closed or there is no data returned back or some other case?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Firebase? I came on here to post a similar issue myself. If I change the temp through the nest device or the web tool, my Firebase listeners are updated. If I try to set a value, the value that I try to set is echoed back to my listener (like there has been an update on the thermostat even though it wasn't changed successfully) then, the correct value (unchanged) comes immediately after.

The weird thing is that it works.... then it just doesn't.  Is this similar to what you've been experiencing?

Update:
Now it appears as if my listeners are not working either. I can query the server using REST successfully.

Update #2:
Now my listeners are working again but still no control.

Update#3:
Well... I think I see my problem at least. I don't know if it will help you (or me for that matter) but here it is...

```
protected void setHighTemp(int value){
    fb.child("target_temperature_high_f").setValue(value, new CompletionListener() {
        public void onComplete(FirebaseError arg0, Firebase arg1) {
            System.out.println("Communicaiton error: " + arg0);
        }
    });
```

Output:
Communicaiton error: FirebaseError: Too many requests

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading the following paragraph in https://developer.nest.com/documentation/glossary#client

> **Client** 
>   An integration of your application or service with Nest
>   devices. When you create a Nest account and sign up for the Developer
>   Program, you can add up to 10 clients to the account.

This might be your problem.